# Linq Parent/child relationship - no intellisense for child

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a parent/child table relation ship

```
ParentTable
  ParentID Int, Identity
  ParentDescription VarChar

ChildTable
  ParentID Int
  ChildCode VarChar
  ChildDescription VarChar

ParentTable.ParentID is a PK
ChildTable.ParentID is a FK to ParentTable.ParentID
ChildTable.ParentID + ChildTable.ChildCode is a PK
```

I have added the above as linq data entites & the relationship is shown in the designer. However, when I try to use the child table columns they are not shown in the IDE intellisense

```
var x = from y in db.ParentTable
                select new
                {
                    y.ParentDescription,
                    code = y.ChildTable....(Only the lamda functions are shown in intellisense here)
                };
```

The is no intellisense for the child table & if i type in .ChildDescription I get an error "does not contain a definition for 'ChildDescription'"

I'm missing something, presumably.

Answer (score 1):

That is because it is one-to-many relationship and your `ChildTable` property is collection of all related children - it is not single child. If you want to select `ParentDescription`, `ChildDescription` pairs try this:

```
var x = from y in db.ParentTable
        from x in y.ChildTable
        select new
            {
                y.ParentDescription,
                code = x.ChildDescription
            };
```

Edit:

You can also do this to get `ParentDescription` and collection of all related `ChildDescriptions`:

```
var x = from y in db.ParentTable
        select new
            {
                y.ParentDescription,
                codes = y.ChildTable.Select(x => x.ChildDescription)
            };
```

Comment: Genius! You've looked beyond my, lousy, psuedo-code example & given me  the info I need to continue. Many Thanks